# Group_by - retain rows based on value in below row of dataset

Tags: r

Hi I am looking to retain rows in a dataset similar to the below:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 |

Where 'Value1' = 1 and 'Value2' in the immediate below row = 1. Under these conditions both rows should be retained; any other rows corresponding to ID 'A' should not be retained. Can anyone help with this please? In this example the below output should be returned:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is keep all the rows where row before has Value1=1 and row immediately after has Value2=1. I've added a few rows to your data to check different scenarios.

```
df=structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A"), Value1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Value2 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

  ID Value1 Value2
1  A      1      0
2  A      0      1
3  A      0      0
4  A      1      0
5  A      0      0
6  A      0      1
7  A      1      0
8  A      0      1
9  A      0      1
```

**edit**: your edit requires you to distinguish between 1's in Value1 and Value2 columns, there are probably a number of options available here, one option is to say that if Value=1 then this starts a new sequence, so the next row needs to have Value2=1 and Value1!=1.

```
tmp=which((df$Value1==1)+c(tail(df$Value1!=1 & df$Value2==1,-1),NA)==2)
df[sort(c(tmp,tmp+1)),]

  ID Value1 Value2
1  A      1      0
2  A      0      1
7  A      1      0
8  A      0      1
```

note the row names/indices.

Comment: Thanks for this, however this method appears to create new duplicate rows when both 'Value1' and 'Value2' have a '1', which does sometimes happen. Sorry perhaps I should've added that to original question. Can you amend code to avoid this and explain for my understanding why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: @JeffWithpetersen Can you edit the table in your question with these cases?

Comment: I have edited the table to explain the issue - I am not sure why but now a duplicate is created in the data frame where entry is '1' in both Value1 and Value2. I suppose I could just de-duplicate the duplicated rwos but would prefer to understand what is causing this issue in the interests of good coding and understanding?

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your help - the code however appears to now be deleting the first instance in an ID group where sequence is similar to the below. I require all 3 rows to be included if a sequence such as this is observed. Thank you:                                                                  1 0
1 1
0 1

Answer (score 0):

- You can try

```
library(dplyr)

inds <- df |> summarise(n = which(Value1 == 1 & c(Value2[2:n()] , 0) == 1))

df |> slice(unlist(Map(c , inds$n , inds$n + 1)))
```

- data

```
  ID Value1 Value2
1  A      1      0
2  A      0      1
3  A      1      0
4  A      0      1
```